# Why is "‐" == "-" false?

Tags: c#, .net

```
Console.WriteLine("‐" == "-");
```

(In case SO changes the encoding, here's a .NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3vvEP9

Writes out False.  It must be some encoding difference, but how can I compare them so that `"‐" == "-"` is `true`?  In other words,  is there a way I can compare strings so that any "-" looking character is treated as equal?

A little bit more background on why I want to treat "‐" and "-" as equal.  I **scraped** a string off a website, saved it in a database, and then **scraped** it again from the website and compared to what was saved. It is no longer the same character. I presume that since I did not use nvarchar, the character got converted.

Comment: Don't use `==`.

Comment: Why do you want to treat these as equal? [`0x002D` hyphen-minus](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d/index.htm) and [`0x2010` hyphen](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2010/index.htm) are different characters

Comment: @ScottHunter Why not use `==`? What else do you suggest to use?

Comment: @Alejandro why not `Equals`?

Comment: @zaggler Well they're strings, not chars, so that'd be one reason...

Comment: @zaggler string/char difference apart, just for readability, as long as both are typed as `string` (not `object`) they're the same, but '==' is just more readable. Scott's comment suggest it's plain wrong, which I don't get why.

Comment: I think @ScottHunter got confused by Java, where `==` is reference equality on strings, and thus is rarely the right choice for comparing strings. While in C# it's overloaded to use value equality.

Comment: If you want two different strings to be considered equal, then `==` won't do the job.

Comment: @ScottHunter I don't think any built-in string comparison function will compare these as equal, because they're different (similar looking) characters. So telling the OP not to use `==` is unhelpful.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: I agree, which is why I didn't propose using one.  OP *specifically* asked how to use `==` to accomplish this task; pointing someone away from a path doomed to failure would seem to be a little helpful.

Comment: @ScottHunter the easiest way to achieve what the OP wants is a custom canonicalization followed by using `==` for comparison. So `==` is not the wrong path.

Comment: @CodesInChaos "I don't think any built-in string comparison function will compare these as equal" You can make your own string comparer and make `string.Equals` consider any strings you want equal to each other.

Comment: It's annoying how many unicode characters have a glyph that is just a horizontal line.  Here are a few to keep you awake at night: `-᠆‐‑‒–—―−⸺⸻﹘₋─━╼╾╌╍`

Comment: @ScottHunter I thought String.Equals("‐", "-") or "-".Equals("-") is the same as "‐" == "-" because the String class overrides Equals. Anyway, I tried Equals methods and it didn't solve my issue.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I've updated my question to explain why I want to treat them as equal.

Comment: you could use linq to check if your dash is in an array of predefined dash like strings

Comment: I don't see how this question is opinion-based.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are different symbols. Add these lines to your fiddle to see it:

```
Console.WriteLine((int)'‐');
Console.WriteLine((int)'-');
```

You can write your own comparison function and treat all different variants of hyphen as the same symbol or you can replace all such symbols in your strings with the one hyphen variant before the comparison.

Comment: Thanks this is useful but it doesn't solve my problem.  Is there a way I can compare strings so that any "-" looking character is treated as equal?

Comment: Sure, replace the smaller hyphen with the bigger hyphen before you compare it with the bigger hyphen: `Console.WriteLine("‐".Replace("‐", "-") == "-");`. Wyck has posted a nice list of glyphs that are all like hyphens, perhaps use it and see if both your glyphs are contained in it eg `Console.WriteLine(wyckglyphs.Contains("‐") && wyckglyphs.Contains("-"));`

Comment: @Alex no, there's no standard way. You can write your own comparison function and treat all different variants of hyphen as the same symbol or you can replace all such symbols in your strings with the one hyphen variant before the comparison.